# android custom listview adapter, cant move text right

Tags: android, android-xml, android-adapter

I want to right align the greyed out text in the image below:

[image]

I have tried layout_gravity and gravity both with values right and nothing has moved it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breweryName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


        <RatingBar android:id="@+id/starbar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breweryRate"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#C7C3C4"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Change your linear layout like this and see what happens .

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


        <RatingBar android:id="@+id/starbar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breweryRate"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:gravity="right"   
            android:textColor="#C7C3C4"
             />

    </LinearLayout>
```